# How to load product from multiple category in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, category-products

I need to get a collection in magento by multiple categories but I am not getting any product when I add more categories.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(7,8)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
                ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
         $this->setProductCollection($products);
        return $products;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following to retrieve products from multiple categories:

```
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('your_cat1','your_cat2',....)))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();
```